# How to compare two string arrays, case insensitive and independent about ordering - JS, ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to compare two string arrays, but case insensitive and independent.

For the example:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] === ['A', 'c', 'B'] -> TRUE

['a', 'b', 'c'] === ['a', 'b', 'd'] -> FALSE
```

`TRUE` when they are with the same length and same values (case insensitive `['A'] === ['a'] -> true`) and independent, about ordering `['a', 'b'] === ['b', 'a'] -> true`.

What I did for now is:

```
areEqual = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const equalLength = arr1.length === arr2.length;

    return arr2.every(arr2Item => {

        return arr1.includes(arr2Item.toLowerCase());

    }) && equalLength;
};
```

, but this is `case sensitive`.

I am using `JS, ES6` with `React`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Is this correct? `['a', 'b', 'c'] === ['a', 'c'] -> TRUE`

Comment: How can `['a', 'b', 'c'] === ['a', 'c'] -> TRUE` be true if `equalLength` is false?

Comment: Edited, and yes, they can't be with different values and equal :).

Comment: What is your expectation about `['a', 'a', 'b']` and `['b', 'b', 'a']`?  Should they be equal?  They have the same length and the same set of values, but each with different multiplicities.  If you say they're equal, then shouldn't `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']` also be equal to them?

Comment: Your third example still says TRUE for arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Yes, this is true `areEqual (['a', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'a'])`, it must be `false`, but in all cases they will be with unique values.

Answer (score 7):

You could normalise the strings to lower case and use a `Set` for checking the values.

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    const lower = s => s.toLowerCase();
    return b
        .map(lower)
        .every(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a.map(lower)));
}

console.log(compare(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'c', 'B'])); //  true
console.log(compare(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'])); // false
console.log(compare(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c']));      //  true
```

Comment: That is just pretty.

Comment: This missing the check for same length.

Comment: OP is contradicting his own conditions though

Comment: @KenoClayton - Very true, I see what you mean. OP's third example says they match (even though `a` is longer than `b`), but OP's code does a length **equality** check.

Comment: His third example must be a typo. They're different length and the second array is missing `b`.

Comment: That is a nice solution.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, op says, unique values, later not, more later unique. hm. i don't know. this solution assumes unique values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `arr1` with a lowercase copy of it. You should also return immediately if they're not the same length, rather than going through all the comparison work when it's not necessary.

```
areEqualCI = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    const arr1Lower = arr1.map(e => e.toLowerCase());
    return arr2.every(arr2Item => {
        return arr1Lower.includes(arr2Item.toLowerCase());
    });
};
```

It might also be better to sort the two arrays, then just compare them elementwise:

```
areEqualCI = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    const arr1Lower = arr1.map(e => e.toLowerCase()).sort();
    const arr2Lower = arr2.map(e => e.toLowerCase()).sort();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```